# Ajax and Mobilefirst

Tags: javascript, ajax, ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I tried now Ajax with mobilefirst to invoke business rules i tried this in my main.js file inside a button click handler:

```
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://brsv2-0cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/vacationsRuleApp/164.0/vacationsRuleProject/1.0",
          async: false,
          withCredentials: true,
          headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + "credentials"},
          data: {
"employeeID": "anything",
"loanAmount": 2320,
"theEmployee": {
    "seniority": 3,
    "annualSalary": 10517320,
    "nbOfExtraVacationDaysBasedOnSeniority": 10517320
        },
"creditAmount": 20000,
"__DecisionID__": "string",
"AnnualSalary": 20000
        }
         }).done(function(response) {
             alert("Success");
           alert(JSON.stringify(response)); // if you're into that sorta thing


         }).fail(function(response) {
               alert("Fail");

               alert(JSON.stringify(response)); // if you're into that sorta thing

            });
```

then i tried to get the error and i found this from the json.stringify(response):

NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest':Failed to load 'https://brsv2-0cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net/DesicionService/rest/vacationsRuleApp/164.0/vacationsRuleProject/1.0.

and when i inspectelement on my chrome browser i find this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://brsv2-0cc90e37.ng.bluemix.net/DecisionService/rest/vacationsRuleApp/164.0/vacationsRuleProject/1.0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: The page you linked you doesn't include *any* JavaScript code. I suspect this is not even RequireJS code, but NodeJS.

Comment: okk this code which starts with var url is supposed to be in the node.js or am i wrong ??

Comment: change the docs customize for type @kryger and make it javascript

Comment: Yay, stateful documentation... :-/. *"Here is a sample code snippet to make a call from a **Node.js** client app. (...)"* <- there you go.

Comment: i'm sorry but what's the difference? Node.js means that i can put this code in my main.js file right ?????

Comment: Some useful reading: http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html . I have no idea what mobilefirst/bluemix does but it's clear that the code is not even supposed to be run in a browser, it is server-side code.

Comment: i'm sorry can you please make me understand what do you mean by : the code is not even supposed to be run in a browser, it is server side code ?

Comment: It means that you'll need to install node.js, save the example file on your disk and run it via `node yourcode.js`, not embed it in an HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing frontend and backend dev together.  The `var url = require('url'),  https = require('https');` code is meant for the Node.Js backend.  The modules referenced above are Node.Js modules.

`<script src="js/require.js"></script>` is frontend code.

You can however use `require.js` on the frontend as well.

If you want to call the Business Rules service from your hybrid app you will need to use something like Jquery using the [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to make a REST API call

Comment: then what am i supposed to do when i have a front-end application with mobilefirst and needs to access business rules service ?!?!

Comment: Are you building a Cordova/Hybrid app or just a web app?

Comment: i'm building a hybrid app

Comment: So you can use require.js but the packages `url` and `https` are Node packages.  I would encourage you to use JQuery and an MVC framework such as Angular.

Comment: use require.js in what ?? i want to send my inputparams and get result just like the code in the above link and i'm not able to do this without the two require declarations ?

Comment: i'm including jquery in my application what can i do with it ?

Comment: You are confusing node with a hybrid app.  The link you posted contains starter code for Node.js.  You will need to use JQuery to do ajax calls from your hybrid app.

Comment: are ajax calls possible ??

Comment: do i have to include anything else for make the calls using ajax ??

Comment: Nope, just use Jquery to do ajax calls.

Comment: i tried jquery.ajax jeff, but i also found now this error

Comment: The question has already been accepted, we need to do it on a new question.